# Encrypt/Decrypt password usage in a custom MembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography, passwords, membership-provider

I implemented a custom membership provider.
I've also implemented my custom AES Encryption/Decryption overriding the abstract EncryptPassword/DecryptPassword of the MembershipProvider.

however, when I trigger ValidateUser, the password is not automatically converted, am I missing something?

Is it supposed to be called automatically or I have to call this method from my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MembershipProvider, but it's almost always incorrect to store a decryptable password. You should be using a one-way hash like SHA256. An exception would be if you had to authenticate using that password to another plaintext authentication system.

Comment: im storing the encrypted passwords in varbinary.
they get decryped when user logs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your encryption routines yourself.

Comment: So I can declare the DecryptPassword function as new?
i.e. public new string DecriptPassword(byte[] password)
instead of the base class pattern public byte[] DecryptPassword(byte[] password)?

Comment: If you're implementing a membership provider, you should be able to just override the functions, rather than use "new".  Then wherever you need to translate a password to/from plaintext, such as in ValidateUser, you can just call the appropriate function.

The reason they are in the interface is to give a consistent way of encrypting/decrypting the password to consumers of your provider, rather than them being in the dark as to what encryption algorithm you used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the calls to your encryption/decryption methods, something like should do:

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    string password=query to get the password from the db/users_list;

    return (CheckPassword(password, storedPassword));
}

private bool CheckPassword(string password, string dbpassword)
{
    string pwd1 = password;
    string pwd2 = dbpassword;

    pwd2 = UEncodePassword(dbpassword);

    if (pwd1 == pwd2) return true;

    return false;
}

private string UEncodePassword(string encodedPassword)
{
    string password = encodedPassword;
    password = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(DecryptPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedPassword)));

    return password;
}
```

Comment: You should not be able to decode the password. If you can then others  can and you might as well store it in clear text. Very bad practice.

Comment: I've just tried to answer someone elses question. Not because someone needs to do something you consider bad practice my answer has to be considered wrong. You should answer the question and tell him that is bad practice what he wants to do!